# How to copy all files in an xspf playlist to a directory?

Tags: ubuntu, media-player, vlc, playlist, xspf

I have created an XSPF playlist of songs that I need to copy to a specific directory, how does one do that? Preferably Python.

EDIT: I have posted this questions several years ago, back when I didn't know much about how things worked. I have managed to do this using a small Python script that I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find this somewhere else myself, so I coded a quick and dirty PHP hack to do it (just now). This is by no means an elegant solution, but does well enough for my purposes. It may be a good idea to comment out the `copy` part in the very end and replacing it with some `echo` construction to make sure your code copies the right files.

Help entry:

```
Usage example: ./copy_xspf.php --e -i myMusic.xspf -o /home/foo/bar
-i filename  or --input filename  - XSPF file to parse
-o directory or --input directory - directory to copy to (needs to exist!)
--help - display this help and terminate
```

Script source:

```cs
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// Quick and dirty hack.

for($i = 1; $i < count($argv); ++$i) {
    if($argv[$i] == '--help' || $argv[$i] == '-e') {
        echo "Usage example: ./copy_xspf.php --e -i myMusic.xspf -o /home/foo/bar\n";
        echo "-i filename  or --input filename  - XSPF file to parse\n";
        echo "-o directory or --input directory - directory to copy to (needs to exist!)\n";
        echo "--help - display this help and terminate\n";
        die();
    }
    if($argv[$i] == '--input' || $argv[$i] == '-i') {
        if(!isset($argv[$i+1])) {
            die("No input filename given (xspf file), use -i filename or --input filename\n");
        } else {
            $filename = $argv[$i+1];
        }
    }
    if($argv[$i] == '--output' || $argv[$i] == '-o') {
        if(!isset($argv[$i+1])) {
            die("No output directory given, use -o directory or --output directory\n");
        } else {
            $outputDir = $argv[$i+1];
        }
    }
}
if(!isset($filename) || empty($filename)) {
    die("No input filename given (xspf file), use -i filename or -input filename\n");
}
if(!isset($outputDir) || empty($outputDir)) {
    die("No output directory given, use -o directory or --output directory\n");
} else {
    $outputDir = rtrim($outputDir, '/');
}

$xml = file_get_contents($filename);

preg_match_all('#<location>(.*?)</location>#', $xml, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1]; // Select only the contents of (.*?), not the entire pattern
$matches = preg_replace('#file://(.*)#', '\\1', $matches); // Remove file://
foreach($matches as $key => $value) {
    $matches[$key] = urldecode($value);
    $matches[$key] = html_entity_decode($matches[$key]);
}


foreach($matches as $value) {
    $base = basename($value);
    echo "Copying $base ...\n";
    copy($value, "$outputDir/$base");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I built a python script to do the same thing!

https://gist.github.com/coppolaemilio/13cdff09abb93ee6ed50f8f300c1327b

```
import os
from urllib.parse import unquote
from xml.dom import minidom
import shutil
import sys

# Read all files alongside this script
for FILE in os.listdir('.'):
    if '.xspf' in FILE:
        DEST_DIR = FILE.replace('.xspf', '')

        # Parse xml and get the file list
        file_array = []
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(FILE)
        itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('location')
        for s in itemlist:
            filevalue = s.firstChild.nodeValue
            filevalue = filevalue.replace('file:///', '')
            filevalue = unquote(filevalue)
            file_array.append(filevalue)

        # Creating folder
        if not os.path.exists(DEST_DIR):
            os.makedirs(DEST_DIR)

        # Copy files to new folder
        for file in file_array:
            head, tail = os.path.split(file)
            print(file)
shutil.copy(file, './' + DEST_DIR + '/' + tail)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I retracted my flag :)

Comment: No problem. I wasn't aware of the link only answers. Makes sense